# Machine Learning - any suggestions to solve Python rounding errors?

Tags: audio, python, mfcc

I am working with Python to isolate voiced segments from music using the [Jamendo corpus for singing detection](http://www.mathieuramona.com/wp/data/jamendo/). Training a model, I break my audio into frames, and have a label (0,1) for each frame.

Unfortunately, due to rounding errors, my labels fall always 1 or 2 frames short.When extracting [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) features from `~Train Music/03 - sample.ogg`, my output is shaped as (13,**3709**).

This seems reasonable because the length of that file is 3797322 samples and with a `hop_length` of 1024, the number of frames works out slightly above 3708.

More details about the MFCC feature extraction in the following code snippet:

```
def MFCC(audio):
    s = [] 
    for y in audio:
        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y= y, sr = 16000, n_mfcc=13, n_fft=2048, hop_length = 1024)
        s.append(mfcc)

    return(s)
```

To now "mark" each frame with the class label (1,0 for singing, no singing respectively), I am converting from seconds to frame numbers but get a maximum value of **3708** (for the longest duration in the file). This is done as per the following function:

```
def labelToFrames(textCorpus):
    output = []              
    for block in textCorpus:
        block_start = int(float(block[0]) * 16000 / 1024)   
        block_end = int(float(block[1]) * 16000 / 1024)     
        singing = block[2]
        block_range = np.arange(block_start, block_end, 1)  # Step size is 1 (per frame number)
        for x in block_range:
            ms_start = '{0:.3f}'.format(x * 1024 / 16000)           # Converting back to milliseconds
            ms_end = '{0:.3f}'.format((x * 1024 / 16000) + 0.064)   # Converting back to milliseconds
            add_to_output = [ms_start, ms_end, singing]
            output.append(add_to_output)
    return output
```

I guess librosa's mfcc function is more complex than my `16000/1024` calculation (?). I have tried using `Decimal`, `math.floor` and also `math.ceil` within my `block_start` and `block_stop` variables, but I can't seem to match my audio frame length. Are there any other techniques recommended to avoid this error?

**EDIT:**

To address some discussion points:

`y,sr = librosa.load("~Train Music/03 - sample.ogg", 16000, mono = True)` followed by `y.shape`, it yields `(3797322,)`. `d = np.abs(librosa.stft(y, n_fft=2048,hop_length = 1024, win_length = 2048))**2` gives a shape of `(1025, 3709)`. Finally performing MFCC on that gives `(13, 3709)`

Sticking with 44.1khz, the label data is referenced 10 frames short.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ["rounding errors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error), or machine learning. What exactly do you want to do? Derive which frame contains the data of $k$ ms offset into the file?With the exception of the first frame, all other offsets are covered by two frames because `n_fft` is 2048 but the `hop_length` is 1024.

Comment: Firstly, this is for a machine learning algorithm so it has everything to do with machine learning. Secondly,I was fairly certain it is a rounding error due to Python's librosa package being more complex on the MFCC calculation than my manual calculations,as  I am always between .1 and 1.1 frames away on my labelled data from the actual frame length of my audio! The thought did cross my mind with the first frame starting at 0, yet, that doesn't seem to explain such a tiny discrepancy of .1 between labels and frames. DSP is not my usual area btw as a data scientist!

Comment: As someone who is trying to answer this question, I am still unclear as to what is the motivating problem behind the question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Essentially, I am curious as to why my vector length is not matching my frame length of audio. My code, to me, seems to ensure that my vector length should be 3709 to match exactly the 3709 frame length of my audio - which I need to train my machine learning classifier. Any help would be appreciated. I am thinking to just trim the final or first frame of audio? Although I find sometimes, depending on the audio file, the vector label is 2 frames short.

Comment: OK, what is inside `textCorpus`? What is the format of that variable?

Comment: It is a list of items outling when there is singing present or not present in the audio. For example, the first item is `['0.000', '37.903', 'no singing']` representing no singing happening between 0.000s and 37.903s. I later convert 'no singing' to be simply 0. And in my above function, try to convert 0.000ms - 37.903ms relate to the audio frames.

Comment: Please note, I have edited the body of the question and it would be good if you had a quick look to confirm that it is still within your original intention.

Comment: Can I please ask if this was resolved?

Comment: It was not. My dataframe was always longer than the length of my labels. So the dataframe was truncated as a quick but ineffective work around.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is amiss here (referring to the code) but here is a list of things that might help:

1. [Librosa's mfcc returns a matrix](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html#librosa.feature.mfcc) that is `n_mfcc x ceil(len(y)/hop_length)`, so no surprises there.
2. Divisions between integers can return reals in Python 3 but not Python 2. In any case, if you have a division of `16000/1024` try to enter it as `16000/1024.0` to make sure that what is returned is a real, even if it is going to be rounded in any way later on. In general, work with reals all the way up to the point where you need the rounding and then round at that point.

   - That's not so important around `block_start` but it would be around `ms_start`.
3. To find the start of a frame containing time offset $to$, you need to $Frn_{start}= \lfloor{\frac{to}{\frac{NFFT-HopLength}{Fs}}}\rfloor$. Where $\lfloor{\cdot}\rfloor$ denotes `floor`.

   - Which, yes, it is essentially what you are doing here since `int` will `floor`.

Assuming that there is no further mismatch between the hardcoded sampling rates and the actual file that is read from the fisk or a mismatch between the audio file and its text file containing the annotations, I cannot see where is the problem with the labeling.

Can you share a specific example where the frame number is off by 1 or 2?

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Since the annotation file is a simple text file, can you please collect the files that seem to be having issues and confirm that the annotations are indeed "correct"? To do this you can use [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). Audacity accepts simple *tab delimited* text files with annotation information. The [Jamendo](http://www.mathieuramona.com/wp/data/jamendo/) corpus includes annotations in space-delimited format and files ending in `.lab`. The conversion is ultra simple using [gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/), to import the file and export it as tab delimited. Once you do that, open the MP3 in Audacity and import its labels from the newly exported text file.

In the following screenshot, I have imported the `emporte-moi.mp3`, converted it to mono and downsampled to 16kHz. This did not seem to have affected the annotations, although certain points, I would have annotated differently because it seems to "cut" when the voice still fades out. But that's a detail probably.

Would be useful to see if there is something going on with the annotations of the files that seem to be "out of sync" with the frame count.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response. On point

2. Unfortunately, the addition of a decimal point followed by 0 did not remedy this problem. 

3. Int indeed floors. I also tried using Python's `math.floor` to no avail. 

If I take in a sample audio file

    `y,sr = librosa.load("~Train Music/03 - sample.ogg", 16000, mono = True)` followed by `y.shape`, it yields `(3797322,)`.
    `d = np.abs(librosa.stft(y, n_fft=2048,hop_length = 1024, win_length = 2048))**2` gives a shape of `(1025, 3709)`. Finally performing MFCC on that gives `(13, 3709)`

Comment: I am working with the Jamendo corpus of audio corpus for singing detection which is commonly used. So I doubt there is issues with the corresponding label files either. I am totally stumped with this one and have been for a couple of weeks now.

Comment: I'm wondering would it be easier to adjust the code entirely to trim the longer of the two?

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol what exactly do you perceive as "the problem" with the two ways of deriving the frames in your first comment here?

Comment: I don't perceive a problem - should I? Everything seems fine to me. Which is why I'm stumped as to why the label vector I have for the audio file which ends up at (13,3709) is only (3708) in length. I really can't see any issues with the code here. But then again - this is my first dip of the toe into DSP and not my area at all.

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol `3797322/1024 ~ 3708.3222...`, which, because of the `.3222...` means that it needs just one more frame even if it has to contain just a very small amount of samples. If you `ceil` that, you get 3709 (?). (Is `13,3709` seconds?)

Comment: I noticed that myself. And yes you are correct about ceiling this. But unfortunately, with some audio audio file labels, they are 2 frames short. Same code as above. So ceiling these will still be 1 frame short. 

I mean, worst case scenario, when I concatenate all my audio files and labels for the files, I can trim the audio files back to the length of the labels. The classifier will still perform, but just not optimally

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol You mean that if you convert the "end" of the last label from Seconds to Frames, it references +2 frames from what you have?

Comment: as with my initial example where my 'end' of the last label is 1 frame short (due to being 3708.3222, which in this case could be ceiled); depending on the audio file and it's associated label, using my original code cited above can lead to the 'end' of the last label being 2 frames short. So it references -2 frames short of what the actual frame length is. So for fabricated example, with another audio file, it may be (3707.322), which if ceiled, will still be 1 frame short of the 3709.

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol There is the sample rate conversion, from 44.1kHz to 16kHz, the "rounding" of (or rather, the change in length) might be affecting the calculation. If the timings were obtained at 44.1kHz, then they are much more accurate. There would be some sort of dilution of precision now because approximately 3 samples are represented by 1 (in the 16kHz file). This all happens beyond the 4th decimal anyway of course, but for long files, these small differences might be accumulating. Could you 1) Have a quick look at which file sizes cause problem, 2) Try not to resample as a test

Comment: Well spotted. I would agree that it certainly seems like small differences are accumulating. I tried your suggestion of working with 44.1 which actually yields a slightly larger discrepancy between my calculations. At the time of writing, I am using this code with 5 audio files which has a discrepancy of 6 frames in length from their associated samples at 16000. Sticking with 44.1khz, the label data is referenced 10 frames short. Very unusual. Again, at this point, truncating might be my only option!

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol, can I please ask you to add all of this information to the body of the question? The reason for this is that it is not entirely clear from the original "body" of the question what exactly the problem is and from the point of view of the board, it is important to keep accurate questions and answers if they are going to be helpful to others too. And it looks like your "problem" might be coming up for other people as well. This is not by any means the end of the search for a solution but a checkpoint.

Comment: Extra information added.

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol Please see amended response.